# What is the difference between "eclectic" and "diverse"?

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives

It seems like *eclectic* and *diverse* have the same meaning, but there must be some difference. What is it?

Did a search on Google but didn't find any info.

Comment: Google does not count as research.  What do published dictionaries say about this?

Answer (score 6):

They are quite different.

*Eclectic* has the definition of *selecting from various systems, doctrines, or sources*, while *diverse* simply means *differing from one another*.

> She has an eclectic taste in music.
>
> People have diverse interests in how water is used.

*Eclectic* also has the definition of *composed of elements drawn from various sources*, which is also pretty different from the second definition of *diverse*: *composed of distinct or unlike elements or qualities*.

> An eclectic group of assistant...
>
> The community is very diverse in terms of...

And unlike *diverse*, *eclectic* can also be used as a noun to describe a person who uses eclectic methods in philosophy, science, or art.

References:  [CED](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/) & [OED](http://oxforddictionaries.com/).

Comment: I don't quite understand the third example user "nyan nyan nyan" provided. Seems like it would be "An eclectic group of assistants". Notice the word "assistant is now plural. I could be wrong. I believe in some situations the words are interchangeable.

Answer (score 3):

For me, diverse is a synonym of *different*, *varying* or *a range of*, whereas eclectic expresses a somewhat unexpected mixture of styles or cultures.

*"Bringing people from diverse backgrounds together"*

*"I have diverse interests, including hockey, birdwatching and cooking"*

*"The museum held an eclectic collection of oriental rugs, African pottery and European art".*